# How to show dropdown items based on selection of other dropdown in angular using primeng?

Tags: angular, typescript, frontend, primeng

I want to display a store which is nearest to that location. So for that i have given 2 dropdowns, one for location(states) and the other for displaying the nearest store(tenants). There are 6 locations and 2 stores only.
[image: locations]
[image: stores]

In the .ts file,
First I get all the active stores(tenants)

```
    getAllTenants() { this._tenantService.getTenantsForPublic(undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,999,undefined).subscribe((data) => {
  this.tenants = data.items.filter((item) => item.isActive);
})
```

}

Then I get all the locations (states)

```
  getAllStates() {
this._stateProxy.getAll().subscribe((result) => {
  this.governorates = result.items;
  console.log('states', this.governorates);
});
```

}

In my .html file

//first dropdown

```
 <p-dropdown #governorateDropdown [showClear]="true" [filter]="true" filterBy="name" placeholder="Governorate" [ngModel]="selectedStateId" (onChange)="updateStore($event)" formControlName="governorate" [options]="governorates" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id"></p-dropdown>
```

//second dropdown

```
<p-dropdown [options]="tenants" [filter]="true" filterBy="name" name="tenants" [(ngModel)]="selectedTenantId" placeholder="Select Your Nearest Area" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

Now I'm clueless on how to filter store value(tenant id) based on the location(state id) selection which should be in the following function

```
updateStore(event : any) {
if (this.selectedStateId == 12) {
  this.tenants.filter((value) => value.id == event.value)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You should reassign value to tenants, not only filtering:

```
updateStore(event : any) {
if (this.selectedStateId == 12) {
  this.tenants = this.tenants.filter((value) => value.id == event.value)
  }
}
```

but anyway with this approach you will override existing array so it would be better to have a copy of the array in a separate object:

```
getAllTenants() { this._tenantService.getTenantsForPublic(undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,999,undefined).subscribe((data) => {
  this.tenants = data.items.filter((item) => item.isActive);
  this.tenantsDB = [...this.tenants];
})
```

and then filtering in this way

```
updateStore(event : any) {
if (this.selectedStateId == 12) {
  this.tenants = this.tenantsDB.filter((value) => value.id == event.value)
  }
}
```

and second dropdown options will be tenantsDB:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="tenantsDB" [filter]="true" filterBy="name" name="tenants" [(ngModel)]="selectedTenantId" placeholder="Select Your Nearest Area" optionLabel="name" optionValue="id" [showClear]="true"></p-dropdown>
```

See working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/djmtda?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdemo%2Fdropdown-basic-demo.ts)